# Enviar un fichero .pdf a un WCF Service desde mi aplicación Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, webservice, pdf, wcf

He conseguido enviar una imagen .jpg a una ruta de mi pc mediante un servicio web WCF,
pero también me gustaría enviar un fichero .pdf

La imagen la envía sin problema pero un .pdf no sabría como enviarlo.

**Mi código en Android Studio:**

```
public void uploadImage()
{
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.imagen);
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
    StringBuilder s;


    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        final String URL1 = "http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetStream";
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL1);

       // ContentBody bin = null;

        httpPost.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data));


        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        String sResponse;
        s = new StringBuilder();

        while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            s = s.append(sResponse);
        }
      

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());

    }

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()){
        case R.id.uploadButton:

          uploadImage();
            break;
    }

}
```

**Mi Código en WCF:**

Envía la imagen recibida y la guarda en formato .pdf en una ruta que le asigno yo.
Todo esto lo hace correctamente, pero en vez de la imagen me gustaría guardar un fichero pdf que he creado con itext en Android.

```
    public void GetStream(Stream imageData)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10000];
            imageData.Read(buffer, 0, 10000);
            FileStream f = new FileStream("C:\\upload\\Imagen.JPG", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
           
            f.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            f.Close();
            imageData.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```